# Cancelling an Asynchronous Method Invocation

Tags: jakarta-ee, asynchronous, ejb, ejb-3.1

I am reading the [Java EE docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkkqg.html#gkidb) and I have a little problem to understand the purpose of the `mayInterruptIfRunning` parameter in the method `cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning)`. I have infered from the docs that the parameter is used to notify the session that the user tried to cancel the invocation and therefore the `SessionContext.wasCancelled()` method should return true (if the `mayInterruptIfRunning` was set to true) even if the cancelation failed. If it is right then what is the answer to the following questions:

1) When would someone call the cancel method with the `mayInterruptIfRunning` parameter set to false and what would it mean?

2) What is the difference in results coming from the methods `SessionContext.wasCancelled()` and `Future<v>.isCancelled()`? Am I right, that the second retuns false if the cancelation failed, whereas the first one returns true even if the cancelation failed provided that one has set the `mayInterruptIfRunning` to true?

**Update:**

Based on the answer I would like to set this question:

Assuming that one calls `Future.cancel()` method with parameter `mayInterruptIfRunning` false. When is the task cancelled and when not? On what factor does it depend? 
If the cancellation happens (succeeded) in the above case, will the `SessionContext.wasCancelled()` return false, whereas the `Futute.isCancelled()` true?

Answer (score 0):

> 1) When would someone called the cancel method with the mayInterruptIfRunning 
>   parameter set to false and what would it mean?

When you **attempt** to [cancel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel%28boolean%29) an asynchronous invocation, you are not sure what the exactly status 
of the server side method is. The method maybe is still waiting for execution, 
maybe it was executed or it has already started.

The parameter `mayInterruptIfRunning` is useful for the last case. 
However, it only makes sense if you have implemented some special logic in the server side, 
I mean, if you check the status of `SessionContext.wasCanceled()` method.

Just an example:

```
//code that execuete in the asynchronus service
while (myCondition) {
    doSomething();
    if (mySessionCtx.wasCancelCalled())
    break;
}
```

If the method is executing, and you call `cancel()` with `mayInterruptIfRunning = false`, the loop won´t finalice until myCondition is false.
If the parameter is true, the while loop will be interrupted.

Notice that for the [moment](https://java.net/projects/ejb-spec/lists/jsr345-experts/archive/2013-03/message/48) `cancel()` doesn´t interrupt the Thread execution.

> 2) What is the difference in results coming from the methods SessionContext.wasCancelled() 
>   and Future.isCancelled()?

As described above, `SessionContext.wasCancelled()` is used in the server side whereas that `Future<V>.isCancelled()`
is used in the client side to determine if the task was cancelled.

Comment: Can you explain further how does it work: " with mayInterruptIfRunning = false, the loop won´t finalize until myCondition is true" ? If you mean "until myCondition is false", then the cancelation is never performed, so what the purpose of calling it  with mayInterruptIfRunning = false ?

Comment: yes, I mean "until myCondition is false" sorry;and yes, if the method is running the cancelation is never performed; The purpose is to cancel the asynchronous call if it is not already executing. I agree with you that the vast majority of the time, cancel() will be called with true, but imagine that under certain condition (imposed for your business requirements) the client code can decide if to interrupt the method execution is suitable or not.

Comment: sorry, but I don't understand the question.

Comment: I have modified the question in my update in anotehr formulation.